# How to get child element in Zend_Dom_Query?

Tags: php, zend-framework, parsing

How to get child element in Zend_Dom_Query?

Example HTML:

```
<h3>
     <img src="wow/img.jpg" />
     <a href="http://wow.com">wow link</a>
</h3>
```

How to get href of link through h3 element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering your example only, you could do as follows:

```
    $testHtml = '<h3><img src="wow/img.jpg" /><a href="http://wow.com">wow link</a></h3>';

    $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($testHtml);

    // get a element using css child selector
    $result = $dom->query('h3 > a');
    var_dump($result->current()->getAttribute('href'));
    // outputs 'http://wow.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is reason to use next construction:

```
$testHtml = '<h3><img src="wow/img.jpg" /><a href="http://wow.com">wow link</a></h3><h3><a href="http://wow2.com">wow link2</a></h3>';
$znd = new Zend_Dom_Query($testHtml);
$result = $znd->query('h3');
if ($item = $result->current()->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)) echo $item->getAttribute('href');
echo '<br>';
if ($item = $result->next()->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)) echo $item->getAttribute('href');
```

Print:

```
http://wow.com
http://wow2.com
```